# How to solve react-native in BASE_MAP.fill(255) function not found at android run time?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

[image]

Do you have any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/react-community/jsc-android-buildscripts

Try to above link. It's work for me.